# PHP, MySQL selecting posts and comments

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with my script which need to select all my posts and related comments. 
Right now I've following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_modified, post_content,update_modified, update_content 
    FROM   posts 
    LEFT JOIN updates
    ON posts.post_ID = updates.update_post_ID";
```

The query works great besides if the post has multiple comments it gives me multiple entries.
I've searched around but unfortunately I wasn't able to re-script my query for my needs. 
I really hope someone can help me out?

Comment: Duplicates of the same comment you mean?

Comment: Yeah, please explain what you mean by "It gives me multiple entries" and we might be able to help you better!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the DISTINCT keyword, used as `SELECT DISTINCT ...` to avoid duplicates. However if I understand correctly your comments are in the updates table and you're pulling `update_modified` and `update_content` into your recordset. So assuming those are (potentially) unique values then DISTINCT will not collapse them down. It might be best to only pull `updates.update_post_ID` with DISTINCT, then pull whatever you need from updates based on the IDs you retrieve when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return only 1 row per post, with all the comments with the post, the easiest way is using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). This returns a csv of all the column data. Assuming that `update_content` is the post comments, try something like -

```
SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_modified, post_content, GROUP_CONCAT(update_modified), GROUP_CONCAT(update_content) 
FROM   posts 
LEFT JOIN updates
ON posts.post_ID = updates.update_post_ID
GROUP BY updates.update_post_ID
```

---

note - `GROUP_CONCAT()` has a [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) default of 1024. If your comments become too long you will want to increase this before running the `GROUP_CONCAT()` query or the comments will be truncated -

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = 10240; // must be in multiples of 1024
SELECT id, name
GROUP_CONCAT(comment) AS comment
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

you will also need to be aware of [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) as this is the limit you can set `var_group_concat_max_len` to.